# How do i check if VNC - Vino is installed on my ubuntu computer

Tags: vino

Hello im kind of newbie to ubuntu , i have installed the latest ubuntu version but i have not installed any external packages , how do i know whether the vino which is default vnc server for ubuntu is already installed and ready to use ? after a fresh ubuntu instalation is it already there and ready to be used ?

edit : i used whereis vino to find out whether its there and it is , how do i start it ? do i have to always manualy start it in order to receive connection to share destkop?

**edit: if i connect to another computer using this destkop sharing program , am i able to grab the files from there ?**

Answer (score 0):

Open the Ubuntu dash and search for *Desktop Sharing*, then click on the icon

Or if you prefer, type `vino-preferences` in a terminal.

Yes it should be installed by default.

Comment: `vino-preferences: command not found` yet when I try to install it, `vino is already the newest version (3.22.0-3ubuntu1)`

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and execute the following command to search your currently installed packages:

```
dpkg -l |  egrep -i 'vnc|vino'
```